# element.remove() in directive sets parentElement/Node of all sibilings to null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where clicking on a button should add another directive, and clicking on a different button should remove the directive. The code below adds the directive, but after the 'Remove' button is clicked, no more elements can be added.

```js
app.directive('chart', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.addNew = function () {
                //add new sibling
                element.after('<chart></chart>');
                //compile so template is inserted
                $compile(element.parent().contents())(scope)
            }
            scope.remove = function () {
                //if parent contains >1 <chart>, delete self
                if (element.parent().children().length > 1) {
                    element.remove();
                }
            }
        },
        template: '<div>' +
                      '<button ng-click="addNew()">Add new</button>' +
                      '<button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button>' +
                  '</div>'
    }
}]);
```

This seems to be happening because the `parentElement`/`parentNode` of all the other sibling directives becomes null after 'Remove' is clicked, even though the element still has a parent and it was a different element that was removed.

I have tried `element.replaceWith('')` and `element.html('')`. `replaceWith()` acted the same as `remove()` and `html()` just cleared the contents of the `<chart>` tag (causing the compile action to redraw the directive when another one was added).

Why is `parentElement`/`parentNode` becoming null when a child element is removed, and is there a way to add and remove element directives from within a directive?

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QgN0Y1AuKxo2mW57uCjI?p=preview)

Comment: element != <chart>. can you remove just the chart tag instead?

Comment: @dandavis `element` is an angular object representing the original chart directive and its html looks like `<chart><div><button>....</chart>`. `element.remove()` is successfully removing the chart tag, the only problem is that it is removing the parent attributes of its siblings as well. Is there another way to remove the tag?

Comment: @quantumwannabe rather than do this via DOM manipulation I would try to use bindings.  You can create a controller for this directive with an `ng-repeat` template based on the recorded length of children -- `addNew`/`remove` would update this length.

Comment: When the `element.remove()` is called, an associated scope will be also destroyed automatically, it might cause the problem if all the siblings are sharing the same scope.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks. The ng-repeat method worked. It's not as nice as having everything contained in the directive, but it works.

Comment: @runTarm Doesn't each child have its own scope? In my directive I have several scope variables (not shown above) that appear to have different values for each directive instance. If this is what is going on, is there some way to force `element.remove()` to destroy the child scope unique to each directive, instead of the parent's?

Comment: That is just my guess, I can't tell unless seeing enough code. May be you could setup a plunker to reproduce a problem and we can took a look.

Comment: @runTarm Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QgN0Y1AuKxo2mW57uCjI?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because all the `chart` siblings are sharing the same scope object, which appears to be the `$rootScope`.

The `scope.remove()` and `scope.addNew()` function will be overridden everytime any `chart` directive is compiled.

Therefore, when you add or remove a chart, the `element` variable inside those methods may point to the last element at the bottom, not the one being clicked.

To solve this just add `scope: true` to the directive definition object to ensure that every `chart` directive will has its own scope.

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/iRcP60u8kBkH9FEhRxBA?p=preview

Additional potential problem, at this line:

```
element.after('<chart></chart>');
$compile(element.parent().contents())(scope);
```

This mean every siblings will be re-compiled as well. It would be better if only the new element will get compiled.

```
var newElement = $compile('<chart></chart>')(scope.$parent);
element.after(newElement);
```